# How to make a fixed bottom header with a absolute positioned side menu to be relative to the BODY?

Tags: html, css

I have the header POSITION FIXED to the bottom of the screen and inside it a "MENU" link that will open a "li" list menu.

**Problem:** The list is set to absolute top and it positions itself relatively to the fixed bottom header. How to make it position relatively to body?

```css
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">
  <ul class="absolute">
    <li>Menu
       <ul>
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>Contact</li>
       </ul>
    </li>
    
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: If you get the list out of fixed header and make it too "position: fixed", it will be positioned relative to viewport and not the bottom header.

Comment: Hi @Alexey, Can you just elaborate it more.

Comment: positioning the .fixed to fixed is positioning to the actual screen (child elements cannot inherit a relative position to the body). What would you like to achieve..specifically what behaviour you would like ?